# Save the History using StoredProcedure in SQL Server 

Tags: sql-server-2008

In my website i have created a procedure (xp_SaveInfo) to save information for new users and if already exist they can update.But now we need to know who are the persons updating and what was they updated. For this i am creating a separate table this table need to fill from using same procedure(xp_SaveInfo) when updating data is saving.So i want to compare and save the data into new parameters and this parameters need to insert into table.

Answer (score 1):

Using [SUSER_SNAME()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174427.aspx) and [GETDATE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) functions give to you ability to know who and when running current script now, something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE LogTable(When datetime, Who nvarchar(100), What nvarchar(max))
GO

UPDATE YourTable SET
  DataField = @Parameter
OUTPUT GETDATE(), SUSER_SNAME(), @Parameter, INSERTED.[OtherFieldsYouWantFromTable] INTO LogTable
WHERE DataField <> @parameter
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg, But i want to store updated data into a separete table

Comment: Thats exactly what it does - you see - I create brand new table LogTable and write into it

Comment: I need modified data save into one tabel while saving this updated data  save in my Logtable for this we need to compare if @parameters contains modified data or not if true need to save this into LogTable.

Comment: CHanged to parameter. INSERTED.* - rows and their fields with new values after update ends

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6659/discussion-between-indra-ramasani-and-oleg-dok)